# How can I get value from cookie to put on an input "date"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Being directly, I'm working on a project that have a filter button, but one of the requirements is to keep the parameters from the filter forms if the user refreshs the page.

The problem is: When I refresh the page with values into the form, just the DATE input resets

I have three forms, and the last is a Date. I managed to make it work for the first two with jQuery but with the date field it just does not work ...

Does anyone know how to solve it? thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("car_result"))
    document.getElementById("car_result").value = localStorage.getItem("item_result");

  if (document.getElementById("car_action"))
    document.getElementById("car_action").value = localStorage.getItem("item_action");

  if (document.getElementById("dei"))
    document.getElementById("dei").value = localStorage.getItem("item_dei");
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  localStorage.setItem("item_result", document.getElementById("car_result").value);
  localStorage.setItem("item_action", document.getElementById("car_action").value);
  localStorage.setItem("item_dei", document.getElementById("dei").value);
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fuid">
  <div class="row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form class="form text-center" id="form1">
        Result: <input id="car_result" type="text" class="form-control"><br> 
        Last name: <input id="car_action" type="text" class="form-control">

        <input placeholder="Initial date" class="textbox-n form-control borderform" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" name="dei" id="dei" /><br><br>

        <button>Filter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with cookies? I ask as your title says cookies, yet the code is clearly using localStorage...?

Comment: `onfocus="(this.type='date')"` .....why not just set the type as date to begin with?

Comment: Because needs the placeholder

Comment: When I refresh the page with values into the form, it resets

Comment: If I refresh the page with values into the 2 first forms, dont reset

Comment: If you need get cookie, use this:
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

Comment: It looks like that should be working. Can you take a look at the contents of `localStorage` and see if it actually has the value from the date input?

Comment: Herohtar, I looked into localStorage and shows just the two ones with their values... "item_result" and "item_action"

Comment: That would seem to indicate that either the `beforeunload` handler isn't running or is getting interrupted.

Comment: I just tested the code in Chrome and it worked as intended. What browser are you using?